# How to order selected Objects

Tags: sorting, object, plsql

In my Pl/SQL procedure, I have a request that select PL/SQL Objects and bulk collect them into a Table.

Here is the declaration of the object and table types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TypPerson AS OBJECT(
   NoSeq                NUMBER(9),
   Name                 VARCHAR2(50),
   Age                  NUMBER(22),
   constructor function TypPerson return self as RESULT
 );

 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TypTblPerson as table of TypPerson;
```

And here is the statements form my procedure

```
req := 'SELECT TypPerson(a.num, a.name, b.age)
        FROM tab1 a inner join tab2 b ON condition';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE req BULK COLLECT INTO tblPersons;
```

This code works fine, but i want to sort the results by a field (of TypPerson) name, and i dont know how to do it.

If I try this

```
req := 'SELECT TypPerson(a.num, a.name, b.age)
        FROM tab1 a inner join tab2 b ON condition
        ORDER BY NoSeq';
```

I get the error **`ORA-00904 invalid identifier`**.

So I want to know how can I do this sort. My procedure receive the name of the field to order by as an input parameter.
May be it is easier to sort the `tblPersons` resulting from the request? In this case how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: The best way to order objects is to use an [ORDER or MAP function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_type.htm), but with your specific example ordering by a.num seems sufficient.

Comment: You don't yet have a valid object in your select-statement - you're calling a construct with the data. Instead just refer the tables where you're reading the data from: `order by a.name`. In your example the use of dynamic sql is unnecessary.